# ksql - Sink topic XXXX does not exist in th e metastore

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I am trying to create data in targetTopic1 based on sourceTopic1 and sourceTopic2. Both source topics are supposed to have same event structure. First target stream is created and then trying to insert data from another source stream to current stream.
Any suggestion?

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM sourceTopic1Stream (category varchar, source varchar, type varchar, id varchar, payload varchar) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='sourceTopic1', VALUE_FORMAT='json');

 Message
----------------
 Stream created
----------------
ksql> CREATE STREAM sourceTopic2Stream (category varchar, source varchar, type varchar, id varchar, payload varchar) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='sourceTopic2', VALUE_FORMAT='json');

 Message
----------------
 Stream created
----------------
ksql> CREATE STREAM targetTopic1Stream WITH (kafka_topic='targetTopic1', partitions=3) AS select 'sourceTopic1' topicname, category, source, type, id, payload from sourceTopic1Stream where id like 'myid%';

 Message
----------------------------
 Stream created and running
----------------------------
ksql> INSERT INTO targetTopic1Stream SELECT 'sourceTopic2' topicname, category, source, type, id, payload FROM sourceTopic2Stream where id like 'myid%';
io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlException: Sink topic TARGETTOPIC1STREAM does not exist in th e metastore.

ksql> show topics;

 Kafka Topic        | Registered | Partitions | Partition Replicas | Consumers | ConsumerGroups
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 _confluent-metrics | false      | 12         | 1                  | 0         | 0
 _schemas           | false      | 1          | 1                  | 0         | 0
 sourceTopic1       | true       | 3          | 1                  | 3         | 1
 sourceTopic2       | true       | 3          | 1                  | 0         | 0
 targetTopic1       | true       | 3          | 1                  | 0         | 0
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ksql> show streams;

 Stream Name        | Kafka Topic  | Format
--------------------------------------------
 SOURCETOPIC2STREAM | sourceTopic2 | JSON
 TARGETTOPIC1STREAM | targetTopic1 | JSON
 SOURCETOPIC1STREAM | sourceTopic1 | JSON
--------------------------------------------
ksql>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in KSQL. I've written it up here: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/2123

The workaround is to not specify `kafka_topic` in your `CREATE STREAM … AS`:

```
ksql>
ksql> CREATE STREAM TargetStream WITH (partitions=3) AS select 'sourceTopic1' topicname, category, source, type, id, payload from sourceTopic1Stream where id like 'myid%';

 Message
----------------------------
 Stream created and running
----------------------------
ksql> INSERT INTO TargetStream SELECT 'sourceTopic2' AS topicname, * FROM sourceTopic2Stream where id like 'myid%';

 Message
-------------------------------
 Insert Into query is running.
-------------------------------
ksql> SELECT * FROM TargetStream;
1541496149897 | null | sourceTopic2 | Foo2 | bar: | x | myid2 | asdf
1541496141671 | null | sourceTopic1 | Foo1 | bar: | x | myid1 | asdf
```

Comment: If I need to put targetstream in existing topic, is there any other better work around? I understand kafka topic created by ksql contains predefined prefixes.

Comment: Only workaround is to call your target stream the same as the existing topic, and for the topic to be uppercase.